# how to synchronize two Odoo (postgresql) databases

Tags: database, postgresql, odoo-11

I need to syncronize two openerp physically distanced databases. One database is on local install, and the second database must on a cloud environment.

Since I lack of good internet access, I cannot have the system working full time on cloud, and the solution is to allow access to the database via cloud (A) and local install (B). When I am on the company, I use the local install (A), and when outside the company, I use the cloud Odoo system (B).

With synchronization, I want to have all data entered on the cloud A available on the local install B and vice-versa.

The synchronization should be time defined and/or on demand.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

you have to search about something called : Replication.

there are of types of replication, and what you are searching about is : Multi master replication.
it's a little bit complex processus to set up a replication between database and monitor that replication, so i will give you some useful ressources.

[Replication Clustering and long pooling in PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling).

[Replication in postgreSQL 9.5  [officiel documentation]](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/high-availability.html)